# Ruby produce modified string from array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have an array

`["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.weather.com"]`

and I would like to produce one long string

`<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>, <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">http://www.yahoo.com</a>, <a href="http://www.weather.com">http://www.weather.com</a>`

I know I can write a for loop, and then append each element of the array to the long string twice. Is there a slicker way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.weather.com"]
urls.collect { |url| "<a href=\"#{url}\">#{url}</a>" }.join (', ')
```

This will give you:

```
"<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">http://www.google.com</a>, <a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">http://www.yahoo.com</a>, <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\">http://www.weather.com</a>"
```